# Django re-group doesnt work as expected

Tags: django

I jumped into learning django recently.

I am rendering my template with citylist like,

```
{'citylist': Cities.objects.all()}
```

And want to reqroup on country in template (same as in django-docs) below:

```
{% regroup citylist by country as coutrylist %}

<ul>
{% for country in countrylist %}
    <li>{{ country.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for c in country.list %}
        <li>{{ c.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

but i get some unextpected results,

```
France
  Strasbourg

Australia
  Penrith
  Sydney

US
  Larsen Bay

France
  Reims

US
  Avenal
```

I dont think i am doing something wrong in my template. Or its a bug??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is not in the code, but with data you are injecting in.

Change your context to

```
{'citylist': Cities.objects.all().order_by('country')}
```

[django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/) mentions that

> The easiest solution to this gotcha is to make sure in your view code that the data is ordered according to how you want to display it.

Comment: Your answer being right doesn't make it OK for your attitude to be wrong.

Comment: Well i apologize for that. But my try was to make him aware of fact that reading docs carefully is must before calling something bug. It was the respect i have for the huge community shaping & polishing the framework, than an attitude. My apology to BRTS though.

Comment: Hey dont worry @taurean. It was my lazy call to see it as bug.

Comment: What if the sort column is being pulled in by a select_related() clause, rather than all()?

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to point to the documentation for another solution.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

You can sort your dictionary in the template.

{% regroup citylist**|dictsort:"country"** by country as countrylist %}